# Call external process in CLR Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, clrstoredprocedure

I know this is not an easy one, nor that it should be very popular. But does anyone know the best way of calling an external assembly with parameters in a trigger or a Stored procedures ? I have tried the CLR strored proc, but I can't add the reference that I need to update a DB2 database. Therefore, I would like to call an external assembly that could do it. Then I would call this assembly in a update trigger.

In SQL Server 2008 R2, the proc sys.xp_cmdshell is blocked by default. So the security guys here will not want to turn that on.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is obvious that you can't treat a CLR project as a normal project and add references to it. Read this article for more information:
http://sqlserver-training.com/adding-external-references-to-sql-clr-projects/-